# Bundles over Function Spaces

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, vector-bundles

Is there any reference on bundles over function spaces? In particular, I am interested in Banach-bundles over function spaces like $W^{k,r}(M)$, where $M$ is a Riemannian manifold. Separable Hilbert-bundles over function spaces are known to be trivial. Is there any reference on this and also on the Banach-bundles case?

Elena